# unable to ssh to EC2 instance inside public subnet in custom vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group, vpc

I have a vpc with 2 private and 2 public subnets. I have added ec2 instance in a public subnet.
The EC2 is given a private ip according to CIDR of VPN and public subnet.

Route table contains a row of 0.0.0.0/0 with internet gateway
the public subnet is associated with this route table.
EC2 is also healthy

I am unable to troubleshoot how to ssh to my instance.
I am new to VPC and this is my first time working with my own so I might have missed something.

[Inbound rules on sg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Be9h.png)

[inbound rules on NACL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg4W2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things to check:

1. Make sure the EC2 has a public IP assigned (enable auto-assign IPv4 address on the public subnet)
2. NACL *outbound* rule allows your IP/ any IP to port 22/ any port since NACLs are stateless
3. The internet gateway is attached to the correct VPC
4. The subnet is associated with the correct route table that has internet gateway
5. The EC2 is provisioned under the correct public subnet that is associated with the route table
6. The SG that allows port 22 inbound is attached to the EC2

Comment: I will check all these and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Just had to enable auto-assign IPv4. It was my first time working with custom VPC. I was also confused that my instance didnt had a public IP. Didnt know that this was required. Thanks again.